# When defining a navigation-case, how can I make a generic reference to the page an action was triggered from?

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I would like to have this navigation case work on any page, but I can't find how to generically reference the origin page on a navigation rule in the tag `to-view-id`:

```
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/public/login/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{LoginBean.login}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/public/login/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

The case translates to: after proper login on page `login.xhtml`, redirect to self, that is, `login.xhtml`

I would like to have something like:

```
   <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
            <from-action>#{LoginBean.login}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>self</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

So if, for example, the login action was triggered from a page with view-id `mypage.xhtml`, I get `<to-view-id>mypage.xhtml</to-view-id>` without defining a particular navigation rule for `<from-view-id>mypage.xhtml</from-view-id>`

In other words, I'd like to know if there is an equivalent of `<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>` for the tag `<to-view-id>`

My current solution is returning an outcome of `null` instead of `"success"` on `LoginBean.login` action success when a parameter `redirectToSelfAfterLogin` is defined, which keeps me in the view I called the action from.

(I also thought of having a `redirectToAfterLogin` parameter and redirect to self by default returning `null` on success instead, but this is more practical for my current scenario)

Anyway, I would like to know if there could also be a faces-config navigation rule based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really needn't set a navigation case, if your intention is to just redirect to the originally requested page. The originally requested page is available as a variable in the request object, with the key `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri` which is easily retrievable in your login bean using

```
   FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   String originalURI = ctxt.getExternalContext().getRequestMap("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"); //the original uri
```

If you really prefer a navigation-config-based setting, you can directly access the requestScope object in there with

```
   <to-view-id>#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}</to-view-id>
```

But I won't recommend that; it's just ugly. That's decidedly page-level stuff you're burying in a config file

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The reason I want a faces-config redirection is the previous two navigation-cases defined by the dev-team for outcome success (and error) on login action were there, so just adding a third one and keep every case handled on the same place makes sense. Simply returning null as outcome worked too, but render condition on `<ui:fragment rendered="LoginBean.isUserLogged">` would not get reevaluated (since the view does not change). I ended up redirecting to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRootView().getViewId()+"?faces-redirect=true"` which gets me the same result...

Comment: ..although you solution seems to be a better fit.